# will EOF changed dynamically when a process open file and read it while the other process is append it

Tags: linux, file

will a disk file read process get to EOF when the file is appended by another write process at the same time and let's say write process is quicker than read process?

Comment: If the writing process is faster than the reader, then the reader will continually be falling farther and farther behind and never finish.  Until the heat death of the universe.  Or a hardware failure.  Whichever occurs first.

Comment: Short answer: it depends.

Comment: Whether or not some other process has the file open, when you get to the end of the file a 'read' will return 0 to indicate that you've reached the end of the file.  If more data is written , a subsequent read may return non-zero.  But `fread` won't make any more reads once a read returns zero.  Since EOF is really only an abstraction related to the higher level IO functions, I think the answer to your question is "no", but your question is imprecise.

Comment: so file read method provided by glib or linux kernel like fopen() and fread() won't use file size in file metadata to read data, right?

Comment: linux kernel provides `read`.  `fread` is a higher level operation.   There would be no point in checking the metatdata since that data may be out of data as soon as it is checked.